# SQL Server Linked Server to txt file faliing

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I've inherited a system with little documentation.
One of the processes seems to connect to a text files on the server. There is a linked server created the points to the folder, using provider jet 4.0 ole db, provider string = text.

The system does checks nightly doing a select from LinkedServer..filename#txt.

This has been working for the last 3 months or so, but now throws error:
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "txtsrv".

I've tried to manually query it, same deal. Txtfile exists, I can open it, it is populated.

Any ideas on why this could be happening, or how to fix it?

Eric

Answer (score 0):

Is there another process that has a connection to the file open? I have seen the same problem a long time ago where a process had left a connection to the file open, causing any further connection attempts to fail. Try running procmon on the server that runs the nightly process to see if there is anything holding a connection open. (Or I guess just try restarting SQL server that the process connects through, that should kill the connection)